# String parsing and matching algorithm

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, version, string-matching

*I am solving the following problem:*

Suppose I have a list of software packages and their names might looks like this *(the only known thing is that these names are formed like `SOMETHING + VERSION`, meaning that the version always comes **after** the name)*:

```
Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver-PROPER.v.122.24-EXTENDED
Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver.123.01
Efficient-Exclusive.Zip.Archiver(2011)-126.24-X
Zip.Archiver14.06
Zip-Archiver.v15.08-T
Custom.Zip.Archiver1.08
Custom.Zip.Archiver1
```

Now, I need to parse this list and select only **latest versions** of each package. For this example the expected result would be:

```
Efficient-Exclusive.Zip.Archiver(2011)-126.24-X
Zip-Archiver.v15.08-T
Custom.Zip.Archiver1.08
```

---

Current approach that I use can be described the following way:

```
Split the initial strings into groups by their starting letter,
ignoring spaces, case and special symbols.
(`E`, `Z`, `C` for the example list above)

Foreach element {

    Apply the regular expression (or a set of regular expressions),
    which tries to deduce the version from the string and perform
    the following conversion `STRING -> (VERSION, STRING_BEFORE_VERSION)`

    // Example for this step:
    // 'Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver-PROPER.v.122.24-EXTENDED' ->
    // (122.24, Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver-PROPER)

    Search through the corresponding group (in this example - the 'E' group)
    and find every other strings, which starts from the 'STRING_BEFORE_VERSION' or
    from it's significant part. This comparison is performed in ignore-case and
    ignore-special-symbols mode.

    // The matches for this step:
    // Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver-PROPER, {122.24}
    // Efficient.Exclusive.Zip.Archiver, {123.01}
    // Efficient-Exclusive.Zip.Archiver, {126.24, 2011}

    // The last one will get picked, because year is ignored.

    Get the possible version from each match, ***pick the latest, yield that match.***

    Remove every possible match (including the initial element) from the list.
}
```

This algorithm (as I assume) should work for something like `O(N * V + N lg N * M)`, where `M` stands for the average string matching time and `V` stands for the version regexp working time.

---

*However, I suspect there is a better solution **(there always is!)**, maybe specific data structure or better matching approach.*

If you **can suggest something** or **make some notes on the current approach**, please do not hesitate to do this.

Comment: Perhaps finding the longest common substring would help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem. You can find many discussions and implementations here on SO and elsewhere on the Web.

Comment: @Jim the longest common substring problem helps with the comparison between two strings, but not with optimizing the number of comparisons to be done. I understand that the OP already knows how to determine if 2 packages equal and only want to do this faster using some sort of clustering.

Comment: Your runtime analysis is wrong: It is O(N^2) and not O(N log N) (constant factors removed) because you are grouping based on the first character only which has a limited range (the alphabet) and you compare every entry to all other entries in the same group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? (Pseudo-Code)

```
Dictionary<string,string> latestPackages=new Dictionary<string,string>(packageNameComparer);

foreach element
{
    (package,version)=applyRegex(element);

    if(!latestPackages.ContainsKey(package) || isNewer)
    {
        latestPackages[package]=version;
    }
}

//print out latestPackages
```

Dictionary operations are O(1), so you have O(n) total runtime. No pre-grouping necessary and instead of storing all matches, you only store the one which is currently the newest.

Dictionary has a constructor which accepts a IEqualityComparer-object. There you can implement your own semantic of equality between package names. Keep in mind however that you need to implement a GetHashCode method in this IEqualityComparer which should return the same values for objects that you consider equal. To reproduce the example above you could return a hash code for the first character in the string, which would reproduce the grouping you had inside your dictionary. However you will get more performance with a smarter hash code, which doesn't have so many collisions. Maybe using more characters if that still yields good results.

Comment: The thing is that I can't always perform **the exact** (package, version) split, usually I'm going to get a (text_which_CONTAINS_name, version) pair. And thus I should be able to match names, which for example match at their first 70% (or something like that). *Can the dictionary be somehow tweaked to make this comparison (also including the ignore-case and -special-symbols)?*

Comment: I suspect this can't be done easily using the dictionary, which is hash-based, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I also think this can be done using some tweaked suffix tree implementation, but I doubt the resulting speed will be worth it (due to implementation complexity).

Comment: I added some more infos. If you require a common prefix of n characters so that there are not a lot of packages which share this same prefix, you can calculate the hash code based on this prefix (in your custom comparator).

Comment: The dictionary version is probably the most easiest to implement and understand and it should be performant enough for even large numbers of n if you do it correct. Even your original version should not be a problem performance wise if your n is in the range of a few thousand entries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably use a DAWG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) here to good effect. I think you could simply cycle down each node till you hit one that has only 1 "child". On this node, you'll have common prefixes "up" the tree and version strings below. From there, parse the version strings by removing everything that isn't a digit or a period, splitting the string by the period and converting each element of the array to an integer. This should give you an int array for each version string. Identify the highest version, record it and travel to the next node with only 1 child.

EDIT: Populating a large DAWG is a pretty expensive operation but lookup is really fast.